# Hive output store for a join query

Tags: hadoop, hive

In hive using the ubuntu terminal, When I do a

```
select * from table
```

I can see the output in the terminal.

Also when I do a

```
select * from table where col=value
```

I can still see the output in the terminal.

But when I do a select using join I cant see the output in the terminal.

For Example:

```
select * from table a join table b on a.col=b.col;
```

I cant see the output in the terminal of anywhere in the localhost web console all i can see is that the query is executed (ok).

Well I can always store the result of the join in the HDFS and see the output of the query.

But isn't there way or any place where I can see the result of such similar queries instantly without having the need to store it. Also storing the result of every join is tiresome.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure there are matching records for this JOIN condition in your tables. Hive throws an Ok when there are 0 records in the output. Also want to know if the Map Red job is getting triggered in case of the Join or not?

Comment: Thanks, There was data mismatch so the join didn't fetch any output.

Answer (score 0):

There are no matching records in tables. That is the only reason the results are not displayed and you are getting only the query is executed (ok).

try to insert matching records in both tables and  run  same query, the results will get displayed on the console itself.